# Error: symbol `__fileimporter_class_MOD___copy_character_1' is already defined

Tags: select, types, fortran, fortran2003

I have this bit of code:

```
    subroutine ReadCharToVariable(self,Format,VarOut)
    implicit none

    ! Declaring Part
    class(FileImporter) :: self
    character(len=25) :: DefaultValue = 'null'
    character(len=25), intent(out) :: VarOut
    character (len=*) :: Format
    class(*), allocatable :: Value

    ! Executing Part
    allocate(Value,source = DefaultValue)
    call self%ReadValueToVariable(Format,Value)

    select type(Value)
    type is (character(*))
        VarOut = Value
    end select
    end subroutine ReadCharToVariable
```

What is does is, it calls ReadValueToVariable with `Value` being a character type. ReadValueToVariable reads then a character from the file and returns it in `Value`. Compiling it (gcc 4.8.5) leads to the error

```
/tmp/cc5JuIb6.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc5JuIb6.s:156: Error: symbol `__fileimporter_class_MOD___copy_character_1' is already defined
```

The error is caused by the `type is (character(*))` line (without the character functionality it compiles). I don't understand what's wrong here, maybe you can help me?

Comment: This might be a compiler problem, describe the version and the flags you are using. There were similar bugs in gfortran 4.8 and some later versions.

Comment: The compiler is `gcc version 4.8.5 (SUSE Linux)`. Compiler flags are `-c` or `-fno-f2c -O0 -g`, both resulting in the same error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely a compiler bug. It is related to, or it is directly this one https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=60359, which was fixed in gfortran 4.9. Note that 4.8 is not supported for quite some time and I think that the release 4.9.4 was also the last one for 4.9. Supported versions are 5 and 6.

Comment: thank you. I will look into it. IT has to install this one first for me, will accept your answer if it works.